# Windows pipe curl output to cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

can anyone help me out here:

```
curl -sSL https://pastebin.com/raw/CHCq9VQt | bash
```

I know this command will retrieve the raw text from pastebin(just python --version) and run that in bash(linux)

I need similar thing for windows,which i remember i did once, asking ai most ai said this:

> curl -sSL https://pastebin.com/raw/CHCq9VQt | cmd
> [image]
> which just gave nothing(i expected python version to return)

some said this:

> curl -sSL https://pastebin.com/raw/CHCq9VQt | cmd /C

that gave a plain line:
[image]

I tried `curl -sSL https://pastebin.com/raw/CHCq9VQt | cmd /C "More"`
but that just echoed python -V,it didnt execute.

I know that cmd is not getting this output from curl as input,but how to solve?

Comment: use powershell instead. `command | powershell` should work

Comment: yeah,but why not cmd? windows should look into in probably

Comment: because **`cmd` doesn't read anything from stdin**, it just starts a new shell. `cmd /C` and `cmd /K` run the command after that and also don't read anything from stdin. [PowerShell OTOH does support running commands from stdin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1). cmd didn't get any updates for decades because there are so many legacy issues that can't be fixed, only powershell is actively developed and it's far more powerful. Read each shell's documentation to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a try and found it errors too. i looked up a solution, its a workaround but try this

```
curl -sSL  https://pastebin.com/raw/CHCq9VQt -o temp_script.bat && temp_script.bat && del temp_script.bat
```

its getting around the issue that the output isnt quite read correctly by cmd so we put it in a temp file and execute that